# What is the programming language with syntax like this?

Tags: programming-languages, scripting-language

I have some scripts written in proprietary language. I want to know whether there is any language with similar syntax like this ?

```
    PROCEDURE MY_PROC_NAME DO 
    {
        DECLARE VARIABLE ABC AS NUMBER 
        [ABC] := 123;

        IF ([ABC] = 123) THEN
        {
            WHILE (TRUE) DO
            {
            }
        }
        ELSE
        {
            RETURN
        }
        #a comment
        SomeFunction(123, 456);
        CALL ANOTHER_PROCEDURE;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a lot of code to go on. Do you have a bit more? Maybe some reserved words?

Comment: What is your aim? To run the scripts as is or to convert them to another language which you can run?

Comment: @lhf I needed to build a full parser and analyzer for this language. So I thought if there is similar language I could use some free stuff out there. This was written by some old folks, so I think they should have inspired by some old language.

Comment: @david.pfx I have added more code :)

Comment: Reminds me a bit of Pascal. But the declarations are different, and Pascal does not use curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like Comal. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMAL

Comment: Comal does not use curly-brackets I think. but it is very close.

Comment: I don't think so. I remember Comal, and it was kind of simplified Pascal. Braces are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is an imperative programming language, with no macro, functional or object-oriented features in the samples provided. It has features borrowed from Pascal (':=') and C ('{}'). The structure is otherwise unremarkable.

There are some distinctive constructs.

1. PROCEDURE name DO {} to define a procedure (but apparently not a function).
2. DECLARE VARIABLE name AS type to define a variable.
3. [ABC] in referring to the contents of a variable.

The lack of a semicolon on the DECLARE line is interesting, but could be a typo.

So, a derivative language probably dating from around the mid to late 1980s. It could even be a dialect of Basic (there were lots of them!).

With some additional code it might be possible to narrow it down further.